# The Maximum Number of Lines Contained in the Point Set of a Finite Projective Plane

Tags: co.combinatorics, projective-geometry, finite-geometry

Consider a finite projective plane of order $q$.  Define $f(m)$ to be the maximum number of lines completely contained in any point set of size $m$, where $1 \leq m \leq q^2+q+1$.  I would like to estimate $f(m)$.  When $m$ is near the ends of the interval, it is not too difficult.  The case of interest occurs when $m = q^a$, and $1 < a < 2$.  Are estimates of $f(m)$ known?